# Issues with XML output for List collections by WCF service with Datacontract

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I am new to WCF and trying to output some XML in a specific format.

Presently my ServiceEvents object holds a collection of ServiceEvent objects (See classes and DataContracts below). When I fetch these objects via WCF the XML output for the collection appends Array0 to the Event element. For the system consuming the xml this is not ideal (see xml below).

Ideally I would like to remove the attribute attr0="EventArray" from the Events element also but it is a low priority.

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IEventAppService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServiceEvents GetEvents();


    }
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Events")]
    public class ServiceEvents : List<ServiceEvent>
    {
        public ServiceEvents(){}
        public ServiceEvents(List<ServiceEvent> serviceevent)
        {
            base.AddRange(serviceevent);
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Event")]
        public class ServiceEvent
        {
            [DataMember]
            public long ID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [DataMember]
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [DataMember]
            public System.DateTime DateStart
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [DataMember]
            public System.DateTime DateEnd
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

        }

<GetEvents>
<MethodParameters>
<Events attr0="EventArray"isNull="false">
<EventArray0>
 <DateEnd>20/11/2011 12:00:00 AM</DateEnd>
 <DateStart>10/11/2011 12:00:00 AM</DateStart>
 <ID>2</ID>
 <Name>Event1</Name>
 </EventArray0>
 </Events>
 </MethodParameters>
 </GetEvents>
```